# What is the Chinese translation for the term "Gee Joon" in Pai Gow?

Tags: translation, characters

Wikipedia doesn't provide the translation for "Gee Joon" in English, and on the Chinese version, it gives the terms 至尊宝，猴王對，皇帝，and 至尊天九, which don't seem to match the transliteration ([https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/牌九](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%89%8C%E4%B9%9D)). Does "Gee Joon" follow a Cantonese romanization scheme, or is it just a English approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is just the shortening of 至尊天九 or 至尊宝 to:

**至尊**.

[Wizard Of Odds](https://wizardofodds.com/games/pai-gow-tiles/story/) mentions:

> Supreme Creator (Gee Joon): Chinese name of the Supreme Creator, which came before anything else.

Gee Joon means Supreme Creator, which fits the characters 至尊.

---

[Chinese Dominoes](http://www.fact-index.com/c/ch/chinese_dominoes.html) back this up pretty clearly:

> This pair when played together is considered a suit on its own, called the Gee Joon (至尊 Supreme). It is the highest ranking pair in the game of Pai Gow, though the tiles rank low individually (in their normal order).

---

Might be some kind of [Gwoyeu Romatzyh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gwoyeu_Romatzyh)/[Barnett–Chao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnett%E2%80%93Chao_Romanisation) kind of thing, not really sure though.

Comment: Oh, I see! I was thinking "Gee" was pronounced like "ghee," but it's actually supposed to be pronounced like the j in "jeans". I guess the romanization is just an approximation of the sound from a British perspective, before formal romanization schemes came into effect.

Comment: Then "Gee Joon" is close in pronunciation to "zi3 zyun1".

Comment: @qpwoe Yeah, "zi3 zyun1" would be the correct Jyutping for 至尊. "Gee Joon" seems like a Romanized approximation of the same.